# Define variable parameter type hints for Callables in Python

Tags: python, pycharm, annotations, type-hinting

I have a class that may contain a function that will be called elsewhere. Depending on what's calling it, it could have a variable number of arguments. One owner might be calling it with the arguments `(event, int, str)` and another might be calling it with `(event, str, bool, dict)`. There are validations that occur later to ensure that the signature matches what is needed by the owner. For type hinting purposes, I need to ensure that the signature being passed matches anything starting with our `Event` object, with anything after being fine and dandy. As a result, functions like `def foo(event: Event, a: int, b: bool)` and `def (event: ClickEvent, c: dict, *args, **kwargs) -> typing.Coroutine[Any, Any, str]` are both absolutely valid.

Given the following example:

```py
from typing import *
from dataclasses import dataclass

PARAMS = ParamSpec("PARAMS")

@dataclass
class Event:
    field1: int
    field2: bool
    name: str

    def get_name(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class SomeCaller:
    ...

class Element:
    ...

class ClickEvent(Event):
    def __init__(self, field1: int, field2: int, target: str):
        super().__init__(field1=field1, field2=field2, name="click")
        self.__target = target

    @property
    def target(self) -> str:
        return self.__target

# The type hint in question
HANDLER = Callable[
    [
        Event,
        PARAMS
    ], Union[Any, Coroutine]
]

def control(event: Event, *args, **kwargs) -> bool:
    pass

def false_control(event: ClickEvent, *args, **kwargs) -> bool:
    pass

async def async_function(event: Event, arg1: int, arg2: int, *args, **kwargs):
    return 9

def function(event: ClickEvent, arg1: int, arg2: int, *args, **kwargs):
    return 7

def other_function(event: Event, caller: SomeCaller, element: Element):
    return 8


class EventHandlerWhatsit:
    def __init__(self, handler: HANDLER):
        self.__handler = handler
        

control_value = EventHandlerWhatsit(control)
false_control_value = EventHandlerWhatsit(false_control)
async_function_value = EventHandlerWhatsit(async_function)
function_value = EventHandlerWhatsit(function)
other_function_value = EventHandlerWhatsit(other_function)

def main():
    print("This works")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Typing hinting warnings appear on the declaration of `false_control_value`, `async_function_value`, `function_value`, and `other_function_value`, all with warnings like `Expected type '(Event, ParamSpec("PARAMS")) -> Coroutine | Any' (matched generic type '(Event, ParamSpec("PARAMS")) -> Coroutine | Any'), got '(event: Event, arg1: int, arg2: int, args: tuple[Any, ...], kwargs: dict[str, Any]) -> Any' instead` . The declaration of `control_value` presents no issue. The assignment of `self.__handler = handler` within the initializer in `EventHandlerWhatsit` also shows a warning of `Expected type '(Event, ParamSpec("PARAMS")) -> Coroutine | Any', got '(Event, ParamSpec("PARAMS")) -> Coroutine | Any' instead` , which I find odd.

All it needs to indicate is "Something that may be called as long as it starts with a parameter that is a subclass of `Event`". The names don't matter. I've played with the definition of `HANDLER` in all sorts of ways, such as defining `*args` and `**kwargs` as `Tuple[Any, ...]` and `Dict[str, Any]` (with and without `Optional`), with the extra parameters, and still end up with the same sorts of warnings.

I'm stuck in python 3.8 and I'm editing in PyCharm, which shows the warnings.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:

[@Daniil Fajnberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19770795/daniil-fajnberg) and [@SUTerliakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14401160/suterliakov-supports-strike) provided perfect answers in the comments:

```py
HANDLER = Callable[
    Concatenate[
        Event,
        PARAMS
    ], Union[Any, Coroutine]
]
```

`Concatenate` allows the annotation to match with slightly different values than what is in the input definition.

Take the following invalid code:

```py
def test_inner(arg: Callable[[str, int, P], Any]):
    pass

def test_input(i: str, j: int, q: str = None, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

def test_outer():
    test_inner(test_input)
```

The linter will trigger a warning because the existence of the optional `q` parameter does not fit the expectation of the `arg` parameter in `test_inner`. Changing the definition of `arg` in `test_inner` to look like `arg: Callable[Concatenate[str, int, P],  Any]`, however, and the linter is just fine.

**A word of warning:** `ParamSpec` and `Concatenate` were introduced in Python 3.10. If you need to use an older version due to environment constraints, use the `typing_extensions` package to provide that functionality.

Comment: Aren't you simply missing [`Concatenate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate) in your `HANDLER` definition? AFAIK you can't just prepend something to a `ParamSpec` without it.

Comment: Seems to work as expected after restoring missing `Concatenate` and `Generic`: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=4e002d1f6c19d94d75802e4dabbdd0f7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Daniil Fajnberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19770795/daniil-fajnberg) and [@SUTerliakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14401160/suterliakov-supports-strike) provided perfect answers in the comments:

```py
HANDLER = Callable[
    Concatenate[
        Event,
        PARAMS
    ], Union[Any, Coroutine]
]
```

`Concatenate` allows the annotation to match with slightly different values than what is in the input definition.

Take the following invalid code:

```py
def test_inner(arg: Callable[[str, int, P], Any]):
    pass

def test_input(i: str, j: int, q: str = None, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

def test_outer():
    test_inner(test_input)
```

The linter will trigger a warning because the existence of the optional `q` parameter does not fit the expectation of the `arg` parameter in `test_inner`. Changing the definition of `arg` in `test_inner` to look like `arg: Callable[Concatenate[str, int, P],  Any]`, however, and the linter is just fine.

**A word of warning:** `ParamSpec` and `Concatenate` were introduced in Python 3.10. If you need to use an older version due to environment constraints, use the `typing_extensions` package to provide that functionality.